# Crear vector de char en C

Tags: array, c

Estoy atorado en una parte de mi código, que parece algo sencillo pero al parecer no entiendo dónde esta el problema.

Resulta que quiero crear un programa que primero le pida al usuario el número de calificaciones que va a ingresar, para determinar el tamaño del vector, y después ir guardando las respuestas (de tipo `char`) en dicho vector, pero por algún motivo, en algún punto de mi ciclo `for` empieza a aumentar el valor (alumnos) que marqué como límite para el bucle.

Agregué dos `printf` dentro del ciclo para ver si encontraba dónde podía estar el error.

Agradezco mucho cualquier orientación.

[image: ejemplo en funcion]

Mi código es el siguiente

```
main() {

    int alumnos = 0;
    char calificaciones[alumnos];
    int i = 0;
    int k = 0;

    printf("Digite el numero de calificaciones (alumnos) a ingresar \n");
    scanf("%i", &alumnos);
    printf("Digite A si el alumno aprobo o F si reprobo \n");
    fflush(stdin);

    printf("El numero de alumnos a ingresar es de %i \n", alumnos);

    for (i = 0; i < alumnos; i++) {
        printf("El valor del contador es %i \n", i);
        printf("El valor de alumnos es %i \n", alumnos);
        printf("Digite la calificacion del alumno %d: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%c", &calificaciones[i]);
        fflush(stdin);      
    }
}
```

Comment: La definicón `main()` no es parte del estándar de C. Se admite por razones históricas, pero no se debería usar. Considera definirlo como `int main(void)` si no vas a recibir argumentos del SO. Más info [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18158541/main-function-defined-without-return-type-gives-warning) y [aquí](http://the-flat-trantor-society.blogspot.com/2014/02/c-standard-quibbles.html). Lo único es que están en inglés.

Answer (score 2):

Esto es un VLA ó Variable Length Array:

```
int alumnos=0;
char calificaciones[alumnos];
```

Y es una característica no soportada por el estándar. Algunos compiladores lo soportan, pero al no ser algo portable es conveniente no usarla.

Por otro lado, en el caso de soportar el compilador el uso de VLA, el tamaño de dicha variable se determina **en su declaración**, es decir, que el array que has declarado va a tener **tamaño 0**. ¿Cómo puedes meter n alumnos en una clase con capacidad para 0 alumnos? pues eso.

Lo que sucede aquí es que vas a escribir fuera de los límites del array, es decir, vas a escribir en memoria que pertenece a otras variables del programa y eso es lo que provoca que tu programa se vuelva inestable

Para arrays de tamaño dinámico (determinado en tiempo de ejecución) debes usar memoria dinámica:

```
int alumnos = 0;

printf ("Digite el numero de calificaciones (alumnos) a ingresar \n");
scanf ("%i",&alumnos);

char * calificaciones = (char*)malloc(alumnos * sizeof(char));

// operaciones con 'calificaciones' ...

free(calificaciones);
```

Y ya que hablamos de malas prácticas, date cuenta que `fflush` solo debe utilizarse con dispositivos de salida. En el caso de los dispositivos de entrada su comportamiento es indefinido (no está determinado por el estándar), es decir, podría funcionar, podría no funcionar o bien podría provocar errores en tu programa.

Comment: Supongo que tiene poca importancia, pero no lo mete en una clase, sino en un vector.

Comment: @EequiisVásquez es C... aquí no hay clases...

Comment: De ahí mi comentario. En tu respuesta escribiste que lo mete en una clase. Sin embargo, me acabo de dar cuenta que con clase no te referías al concepto de clase en programación, sino a un aula o conjunto de alumnos. Error de interpretación mío.

Comment: @EequiisVásquez vale, ahora ya si te entiendo... estaba casi tan perdido como tú